# Spring Web Services and Soap

Tags: web-services, spring, soap, spring-ws, springsource

What is the best class/bean to use for a Java Soap Web Service?  I am a .NET guy and can't really tell from any articles on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to use spring-ws, just follow the tutorial on
[Spring Source](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/tutorial.html). Basically, you have to

1. define a dispatcher for SOAP requests in your web.xml file
2. define a given WSDL in your spring-ws context XML file
3. annotate any Bean with @Endpoint, and one method with @PayloadRoot(...)

These are the first basic steps to create a web service endpoint with Spring WS.

Answer (score 0):

for those looking for a simple tutorial, I recommend: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/11/jaxws-with-spring-and-maven-tutorial.html makes use of spring-ws and spring-web